# Automatization of code generation in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, code-generation

I'd like to setup some code generation scripts in my Unity project. I'd like to run code generator every time when refreshing project. I did something like that:

```
    public static class CustomRefresh
    {
        [MenuItem("Tools/CustomRefresh")]
        public static void Refresh()
        {
            GenerateSomeCodeFiles();
            AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

And in fact after using Tools/CustomRefresh option, new code files are generated and present in project folder, however they are not compiled. I have to use Tools/CustomRefresh second time to get it compiled. How can I make this process properly automatic, so I don't have to refresh twice?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Refresh()` does not recompile assets all of the time. I would try something along the lines of

```
#if UNITY_2019_3_OR_NEWER
                 CompilationPipeline.RequestScriptCompilation();
#elif UNITY_2017_1_OR_NEWER
                 var editorAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Editor));
                 var editorCompilationInterfaceType = editorAssembly.GetType("UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface");
                 var dirtyAllScriptsMethod = editorCompilationInterfaceType.GetMethod("DirtyAllScripts", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
                 dirtyAllScriptsMethod.Invoke(editorCompilationInterfaceType, null);
 #endif
```

Make sure to include `using UnityEditor` at the top of the script. The above methods will force Unity to recompile the actual scripts. If you are in a newer version of Unity, you can ignore the code in `2017_1_OR_NEWER` and just use the one-line solution as Unity exposed a public method to recompile scripts in versions of `2019_3_OR_NEWER`.

Comment: Unfortulatly, the same problem appears. No visible changes until second attempt.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compilation.CompilationPipeline.RequestScriptCompilation.html) specify that it is an Asynchronous task. It could just be taking a while. Possibly try a `CompilationPipeline.RequestScriptCompilation();` and after use a `Refresh()`.

Comment: Actually, even better, you can subscribe to the event that is called when the compilation is finished. It is called in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compilation.CompilationPipeline-compilationFinished.html). Subscribe to this event before calling the CompliationPipeline and in the callback the data should be updated. If it is not updated there, then call a `Refresh()` there.